# How does the UK government spend Stamp Duty Land Tax?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

Google has been unable to find an answer to this question, even the "everything you need to know about SDLT articles" never cover how the tax revenue is spent by the government.

I appreciate this could be because it's not specifically allocated to anything and goes into some kind of wider pool of revenue.

When I get my council tax bill, I receive a letter explaining what the revenue gets allocated to, for example, refuse collection, roads, police and crime commissioner and so on.

Is there a similar thing for SDLT?

Answer (score 2):

Stamp Duty Land Tax is paid to HM Customs and Revenue (in England and Wales) and so goes into the general fund of the UK National Government. That means it isn't allocated to anything specific. It's essentially divided up in exactly the same way that all other tax income is. You can certainly find descriptions of how the national government spends its money.

Your council tax bill works the same, but is spent by the local council, not the national government.

Comment: Since 2014 HMRC sends [annual tax summaries](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/annual-tax-summary) showing "how the national government spends its money". These are not without controversy, of course. Little things such as making 'pensions' a separate category from 'welfare', and the like.

Comment: No, your 'personalised' tax summary as well as telling you how much tax you paid also pro-rates that against all government spending and (from that link target) "shows how the government spent your tax and NICs. You can read about how these numbers are calculated in [how public spending was calculated in your tax summary](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/how-public-spending-was-calculated-in-your-tax-summary)."